# Camera FOV is messed up

Tags: camera

[image]

How DO i make it go back to normal, I entered the POV of a camera and when I exited out of the camera it left me stuck like this.

Comment: I guess the answer given here is the solution to your problem, but "stuck like this" is not really an expressive description of what is not "normal" here. What I see is a normal ortographic view of the 3D viewport. Some people always work like this. I suspect you want to go back to the perspective view - but the question doesn't really reflect this. And the title is misleading too, since you are out of camera view. Anyway, if you want the perspective view, click the button as shown in the answer below or use the shortcut: _Numpad 5_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Over here~]
Here, click this.
You probably just misclicked. Also, since you asked a question like this, I'll assume that you are new to Blener, like me. I strongly recommand you to [this official tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF1qEhBSfq4&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6&ab_channel=Blender). Tho it is based on 2.8, it helps me a lot, and your problem is mentioned **at 2:50 in the second video** of this series.